# Joining three tables with sums and counts

Tags: mysql

I have three tables

**[users]**

```
id
name
email
```

**[transactions]**

```
id
user_id
amount
points_rewarded
```

**[redemptions]**

```
id
user_id
points_redeemed
```

I want to query the database to get the following fields

```
users.id
users.name
transactions   //   Number of transactions
redemptions    //   Number of redemptions
points         //   Sum of points_rewarded - sum of points_redeemed
```

I can manage to join users table with either transactions or redemptions but I can't seem to join all three in one query.

**[users+transactions]**

```
SELECT users.id,users.name,COUNT(transactions.id) AS transactions,SUM(transactions.points_rewarded) AS points_rewarded FROM users LEFT JOIN transactions ON users.id=transactions.user_id GROUP BY users.id, users.name
```

Which gives the correct values for users.id, users.name, transactions and points_rewarded.

**[users+redemptions]**

```
SELECT users.id,users.name,COUNT(redemptions.id) AS redemptions, IFNULL(SUM(redemptions.points_redeemed),0) AS points_redeemed FROM users LEFT JOIN redemptions ON users.id=redemptions.user_id GROUP BY users.id, users.name
```

Which gives the correct values for users.id, users.name, redemptions and points_redeemed.

If I simply left join both using

```
SELECT users.id,users.name,COUNT(transactions.id) AS transactions,COUNT(redemptions.id) AS redemptions,SUM(transactions.points_rewarded) - IFNULL(SUM(redemptions.points_redeemed),0) AS points FROM users LEFT JOIN transactions ON users.id=transactions.user_id LEFT JOIN redemptions on users.id=redemptions.user_id GROUP BY users.id, users.name
```

I get wrong values for the redemptions columns. I basically get all the points_rewarded values multiplied by the total number of redemptions making the points (points_rewarded - points_redeemed) negative values which is not possible.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's because left joins will returning a union of records, which may alter the sums which otherwise should and would apply to each set independantly (like it does when you use 2 separate queries)

So yeah, both queries still have to coexist within a "master" query:

```
SELECT users.id, 
       users.name, 
       t.transactions, 
       r.redemptions, 
       t.points_rewarded - r.points_redeemed AS points 
FROM   users 
       LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            users.id, 
            COUNT(*) AS transactions,
            COALESCE(SUM(transactions.points_rewarded),0) AS points_rewarded 
        FROM users LEFT JOIN transactions ON users.id=transactions.user_id 
        GROUP BY users.id
       ) t ON users.id = t.user_id 
       LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            users.id,
            COUNT(*) AS redemptions, 
            COALESCE(SUM(redemptions.points_redeemed),0) AS points_redeemed 
        FROM users LEFT JOIN redemptions ON users.id=redemptions.user_id 
        GROUP BY users.id
       ) r ON users.id = r.user_id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Sebas' answer the final query that I went with is:

```
SELECT 
  users.id, 
  users.name, 
  COALESCE(t.transactions,0) AS transactions, 
  COALESCE(t.points_rewarded,0) AS points_rewarded, 
  COALESCE(r.redemptions,0) AS redemptions, 
  COALESCE(r.points_redeemed,0) AS points_redeemed,
  COALESCE(t.points_rewarded,0)-COALESCE(r.points_redeemed,0) AS points 
  FROM users 
  LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT 
       users.id, 
       transactions.user_id, 
       COALESCE(COUNT(transactions.id),0) AS transactions, 
       COALESCE(SUM(transactions.points_rewarded),0) AS points_rewarded 
       FROM users 
       LEFT JOIN transactions ON users.id=transactions.user_id 
       GROUP BY users.id) t 
  ON users.id=t.user_id 
  LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT 
       users.id,
       redemptions.user_id,
       COALESCE(COUNT(redemptions.id),0) AS redemptions,
       COALESCE(SUM(redemptions.points_redeemed),0) AS points_redeemed
       FROM users LEFT JOIN redemptions ON users.id=redemptions.user_id
       GROUP BY users.id) r 
  ON users.id=r.user_id
```

Now all that's left is converting this to something more "eloquent" ;-)